# How to auto open a chat in XMPP chat client Converse.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, converse.js

I want to integrate XMPP chat into my website. Tried to create just a bare bone chat, where it should auto login and auto open a chat window. It just can auto login, but does nothing after that.

The whole code is as below. Why it does not auto open a chat window?

```
<body>


<script>
    converse.initialize({
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        allow_muc: false,
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        auto_login: true,
        authentication: 'login',
        jid: 'kelvin@xmpp.mydomainhere.com',
        password: 'kelvin',
        websocket_url: 'wss://xmpp.mydomainhere.com:5280/websocket'
    });

    console.log("000");

    converse.plugins.add('myplugin', {
        initialize: function () {
            this._converse.chats.open('jacky@xmpp.mydomainhere.com')

            var msg = converse.env.$msg({
                from: 'kelvin@xmpp.mydomainhere.com',
                to:'jacky@xmpp.mydomainhere.com',
                type:'chat'
            });
            this._converse.send(msg);
        }
    });

    </script>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.0.0 and onwards, plugins need to be whitelisted (via the [whitelisted_plugins](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#whitelisted-plugins) setting), otherwise they are not initialized.

So you simply have to add `whitelisted_plugins: ['myplugin']` to your `converse.initialize` call.

Besides that, you also need to register the plugin before calling `converse.initialize`.

Comment: I added the whitelisted_plugins, as following, but it still does not work. Any help? Thanks.

converse.initialize({
        whitelisted_plugins: ['myplugin'],
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
        allow_muc: false,
        auto_login: true,
        authentication: 'login',
        jid: 'kelvin@xmpp.mydomainhere.com',
        password: 'kelvin',
        websocket_url: 'wss://xmpp.mydomainhere.com:5280/websocket'
    });

Comment: You need to register the plugin before calling converse.initialize. I updated my answer.

Comment: I have switched the two code blocks. Now the plugin block comes before the converse.initialize block. But it still does not work.